# Could not load type 'AmbiguousActionException' from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, after migrating .NET Core from 2.2 to 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

We are migrating our APIs from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET Core 3.1 and we have a middleware which catch exceptions and returns an HTTP Code. This is the Invoke method:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context){
try
{
    _logger.LogDebug("Invoke: Before _next invoke.");
    await _next(context);
    _logger.LogDebug("Invoke: Get Response Body.");
    context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    string text = await new StreamReader(context.Response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    _logger.LogDebug("Invoke: Process the response and continue.");
    ProcessingRestfulResponse(context, text);
}
catch (NotFoundException notFound)
{
    _logger.LogDebug(notFound, "Invoke - NotFoundException.");
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(ChangeResponseMiddleware(context, notFound, HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
}
... // Another catches
catch (AmbiguousActionException aaex)
{
    _logger.LogDebug(aaex, "Invoke - AmbiguousActionException.");
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(ChangeResponseMiddleware(context, aaex, HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.LogCritical(ex, "Invoke - Exception: " + ex.Message);
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(ChangeResponseMiddleware(context, ex, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError));
}
```

}

As you can see, we have a reference to AmbiguousActionException. This code is throwing the following exception in runtime

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.AmbiguousActionException' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=3.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

And the project file has a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 2.2.5

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">


<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <Version>2.0.0.0-beta</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Help me please :)

Comment: The problem is *caused* by those old packages. Both `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions` are 2.2 packages. Remove them

Comment: The docs contain an article on [migrating from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio). Check the section [Remove Obsolete Package References](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#remove-obsolete-package-references)

Comment: You're right, I should remove those packages. The AmbiguousActionException is now part of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure namespace in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=3.1.0.0 assembly. Thank you very much!